# isNaN not firing until 2 characters are typed in

Tags: javascript

My HTML code is:

```
<input onKeyPress="validateA(this.value)" type="text" id="AAA" name="AAA" size="10" placeholder="A">
<span id="aspan" class="validate">  </span>
```

and my Javascript is:

```
function validateA(valueOfAAA) {
if (isNaN(valueOfAAA)) {
    document.getElementById('aspan').innerHTML="Please enter a numerical value.";

}
else {
    document.getElementById('aspan').innerHTML="";
}

}
```

To clarify, my question is:

Why is the `innerHTML="Please enter a numerical value."` not firing until two letters OR numbers are typed into my input box?

Comment: Is the whole function not firing, or is it just the `isNaN` part that isn't being triggered for the first few characters?

Comment: @PeterOlson The whole thing was not firing until I entered both characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `onKeyPress()` to `onKeyUp()`
because when keypress triggered, the actual value of input is not captured yet.